# 22.04 software update downloaded 5.15 kernel but laptop still boots into 5.14

Tags: grub2, kernel, 22.04, thinkpad

On a ThinkPad X1 Carbon 9th gen, software update installed the 5.15 kernel, but machine still boots into 5.14, which is puzzling. I'm guessing it has something to do with the 5.14 kernel being "OEM" (not sure why I have that since I installed Ubuntu after purchase, not pre-loaded). $ uname -r returns "5.14.0-1048-oem"

Two questions: 1) How can I (or should I) get the machine to use the more recent kernel? 2) Does the OEM version get automatically updated at some point?

I assume grub is involved in some way -- :)

Comment: You didn't state if you're asking about Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS, or Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS; but I'll assume Ubuntu Desktop.  The `ubiquity` installer for Ubuntu Desktop will install the OEM kernel if your hardware is recognized as benefiting in some way by the OEM choice (*there are many on installation media*) over the GA/HWE kernel stack. If the installer put it on your system, it'll be auto-upgraded (or switched) as better options exist. Not all 22.04 media includes OEM kernel options.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I'm using the desktop OS. My primary reason for wondering about this is that I understand the 5.15 kernel has much better support for sound output than earlier ones. I've been using Ubuntu for more than a decade but it has never been even close to the quality of sound you get on ThinkPads running Windows. In this case, by the way, I upgraded from 20.04 rather than doing a full re-installation.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop media had OEM options as well, but I'm not familiar enough to advice there sorry (I'm involved with a flavor (Lubuntu) that doesn't include/use any on our media, thus I don't need to keep up with what's available for each release). If the installer, or [*ubuntu-release-upgrader* tool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) put it there, if it was me I'd feel safe.  I also know little about sound differences sorry.